# How to save a tensorflow seq2seq model use save_model api?

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot

Now I want to train a chatbot model with tensorflow seq2seq, and deploy the chatbot on server. I select tensorflow serving to do this work, but only saved_model(*.pb) format model can be loaded! So if anyone could ask me how to save chatbot with saved_model api?